# How to Query Gclids, Conversion Time, and Conversion Value for a Specific Conversion Name using Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

Query Gclids for an specific ConversionName and period

Through Google ads API,  Is it possible to query those fields below? I need the list of Gclids, when the conversion happened, conversion value,  for only this conversion name “reg” and the period would be: Last 7 days.

GCLID         ConversionName    Conversion Time      ConversionValue
EAIaIxxxxxx       reg           2024-02-12T11:22:23     1
CjwKCxxxxxx   reg           2024-04-13T18:57:03     3

We are testing on the Query Builder, but when using the Conversion_Action table, we can’t see all the fields
Could you please help us to build the query?

SELECT GClid(?), conversion_action.name, ConversionTime(?), ConversionValue(?) FROM conversion_action WHERE conversion_action.name = 'reg' and date_time(?)=Last_7_Days

We are not finding those fields: GClid(?), ConversionTime(?),ConversionValue(?),date_time(?)
Many Thanks